# Calculating the normal to a surface $S \equiv \{(x,y,u(x,y)\}$

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

Either I'm missing something obvious or my lecture notes are making a large jump because I can't seem to see why this is the case:

> For an equation $$a(x,y) u_x + b(x,y)u_y = c(x,y)$$ consider the graph
>   of this function given by $$S \equiv \{(x,y,u(x,y)\}$$and from
>   calculus, the normal to this surface $S$ is given by $$N(x,y) = (u_x(x,y), u_y(x,y), -1).$$

Can someone please explain why the normal is given by this formula? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your surface $S$ is parametrized by

$$
\varphi (x,y) = (x, y, u(x,y)) .
$$

Hence, its tangent plane is generated by

$$
\varphi_x = (1, 0, u_x) \qquad \text{and}\qquad \varphi_y = (0,1,u_y) \ .
$$

You can easily check that your vector $N$ is orthogonal to both of them:

$$
\varphi_x \cdot N = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \varphi_y \cdot N = 0 \ .
$$